# How to enable a JButton when only the enable textfield is filled in

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am making a game for a project. My game can have 2-6 players. On the start screen, my text fields for player names are enabled depending on how many players will play the game. The problem I am encountering is that I must have all the fields filled regardless of whether they are enabled or disabled, to have the start button enabled. My objective is that I want the start button to be enabled ONLY when the enabled text fields are filled. I would appreciate the help!

I have only provided the required code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAFea.png)

Regards

```
Controller Class:

mainView.checkNameFields(new CheckField());

...
Rest of code
...

class CheckField implements DocumentListener{

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            mainView.checkData();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            mainView.checkData();
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    }
```

```
View Class

        p1 = new JTextField(3);
        p2 = new JTextField(3);
        p3 = new JTextField(3);
        p4 = new JTextField(3);
        p5 = new JTextField(3);
        p6 = new JTextField(3);

        nameFields = new ArrayList<>();
        nameFields.add(p1);
        nameFields.add(p2);
        nameFields.add(p3);
        nameFields.add(p4);
        nameFields.add(p5);
        nameFields.add(p6);

        p1.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        p2.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        p3.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        p4.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        p5.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        p6.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14));

        p1.setEditable(true);
        p2.setEditable(true);
        p3.setEditable(false);
        p4.setEditable(false);
        p5.setEditable(false);
        p6.setEditable(false);

...
Rest of Code
...

public boolean ifNameFieldFull(){


        for(JTextField eachNameField : nameFields){

            if(!eachNameField.isEnabled()){
                continue;
            }
            else if(eachNameField.getText().trim().length() == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


public void checkData(){

    startGame.setEnabled(ifNameFieldFull());
}

public void checkNameFields(DocumentListener fieldCheck){
    p1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(fieldCheck);
    p2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(fieldCheck);
    p3.getDocument().addDocumentListener(fieldCheck);
    p4.getDocument().addDocumentListener(fieldCheck);
    p5.getDocument().addDocumentListener(fieldCheck);
    p6.getDocument().addDocumentListener(fieldCheck);
}
```

Comment: Code looks reasonable, not sure what the problem is. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30923059/131872 for a reusable solution. I just changed the code in the `isDataEntered()` method to see if the text field is enabled AND the text length is 0. Worked fine for me.

Comment: i used if(eachNameField.isEnabled() && eachNameField.getText().trim().length() == 0)

Did you do it any differently than this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I used in my class. I can only verify it worked with my class. I posted complete working code. You only need to modify a single line of code in the class I provided. The code yo posted here can't be compiled so I can't guess what you might be doing wrong. Why would you not choose to use reusable code, instead of hardcode all the code in your class to specific variables?