# looping through JTextField to getText and check if empty

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield

I am trying to loop through `JTextField` after creating an ArrayList `ArrayList<JTextField> textfields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();` And I need to check if these JTextFields are empty but I am recieving `AWT-EventQueue-0` Error.

> Adding All JTextFields in the ArrayList

`// textfields.add(AllTextFields)`

> Looping Through The ArrayList

```
for(int i=0; i<textfields.size(); i++){
    if(!textfields.get(i).getText().equals("")){
       callFrame();
    }
}
```

> Explanation

All I am trying to do here is to check if `at least one` of these JTextFields are empty, if one is empty do not call the other frame. If `ALL` JTextFields are not empty, call the new frame. I am receiving the AWT-EventQueue-0 - NullPointerException. The fact that I am not accessing a variable that's not pointing to something.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30919644/validation-of-text-fields-and-contact-no-text-field/30923059#30923059 for a slightly different approach. The "Submit" button on your form is disabled by default and will only be enabled when text is entered in each of the text fields.

Answer (score 2):

If i understood you correctly, then your code would not work, since you are calling the other frame if one of the textfields is not empty (not if all of them are not empty). I would do something like this:

```
    boolean allFilled = true;
    for (JTextField textfield : textfields) {
        String text = textfield.getText();
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            allFilled = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (allFilled) {
        // Call the other Frame if every Textfield has a value
        callFrame();
    }
```

Here you dont have to loop over all Textfields since you just end the loop when you found atleast one empty field.

Also could you please post the full Stacktrace (error message)? You only shared
**AWT-EventQueue-0** but that is the Thread name where the error occurred.

Comment: I am having the same error, if I changed the loop with a boolean

Comment: In the error Stacktrace you should see the line where the error occurred. If it is still a nullpointerexception then you are trying to access a variable that is null. Maybe one of your textfields is null or the textfield returns null as the text (not sure since i never used swing). You could also try to debug and look at the variables to see what is null.

Comment: I am trying to add ```if(textfields.get(i).isEditable == true)``` so it would check all editable textfields because maybe while looping its looping on non-editable textfields so it will be null. But still I tried many answers and the same error is showing. I am having it at the line of ```textfields.get(i).getText().equals("")```

Comment: yeah then it could be one of the following things that is null:
- the list (textfields)
- the textfield that is returned from get(i)
- the text that is returned from getText()

Comment: I am trying to print the first element of the ArrayList using ```System.out.println(textfields.get(0).getText();``` but its showing nothing. Maybe the ArrayList is empty i will double check it.

Comment: I am 90% sure it's from the textfields, because after printing it is showing me the error. Maybe the ArrayList isn't being filled with these JTextFields? any idea what to do or how to be sure about it?

Comment: i would need to see more code for that :)